# Print vs Return with time.sleep in python

Tags: python, time

Can someone explain to me why using "print" in the following will continue to re-run the code, but using "return" will only run it once?  And how would you have the code re-run its self using "return" as opposed to "print"??

Thanks ya"ll!

```
def stop():
    while True:
        oanda = oandapy.API(environment="practice", access_token="xxxxxxxx")
        response = oanda.get_prices(instruments="EUR_USD")
        prices = response.get("prices")
        asking_price = prices[0].get("ask")
        s = asking_price - .001
        print s
    time.sleep(heartbeat)


print stop()
```

VS

```
def stop():
    while True:
        oanda = oandapy.API(environment="practice", access_token="xxxxxxxxxx")
        response = oanda.get_prices(instruments="EUR_USD")
        prices = response.get("prices")
        asking_price = prices[0].get("ask")
        s = asking_price - .001
        return s
    time.sleep(heartbeat)


print stop()
```

Comment: If you don't use `return`, you're effectively creating an infinite while loop, unless you use a `break` statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Q.**

> Can someone explain to me why using "print" in the following 
>   will continue to re-run the code, but using "return" will only run it once?

**A.**

The [*return*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement) exits the function entirely so that it cannot be restarted.

**Q.**

> And how would you have the code re-run its self using 
>   "return" as opposed to "print"?

Use ["yield"](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-yield-statement) instead of "return" to create a kind of resumable function called a [generator](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/classes.html#generators).

For example:

```
def stop():
    while True:
        oanda = oandapy.API(environment="practice", access_token="xxxxxxxx")
        response = oanda.get_prices(instruments="EUR_USD")
        prices = response.get("prices")
        asking_price = prices[0].get("ask")
        s = asking_price - .001
        yield s

g = stop()
print next(g)
print next(g)
print next(g)
```

Comment: Thats awesome @Raymond Hettinger!  Thanks a lot, i'm working with 'yield' now!

Answer (score 4):

```
return s
```

returns from `stop()`. It does **not** `continue` the `while` loop. If you want to stay in the loop, don't return from the function.

Comment: Of course you can. But it depends on what you want to do. Do you want an infinite loop? Then don't return. If you want to exit the loop at some point, check for a condition and return.

Comment: It's because you're using `return` in a function, it has nothing to do with the loop. `return` always ends the function it's in, loop or no loop.